# Dialog Flow CX: Fulfill an Intent when using StreamingDetectIntentRequest, rather than webhook?

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

Performing an Intent fulfillment in Dialog Flow CX using the webhook is straight forward.

However, I'm looking to fulfill the intent when streaming, using the StreamingDetectIntentRequest. I did see the SessionsClient.fulfill_intent function, but this is for a MatchIntent query, rather than when streaming.

Anyone know how to return a fulfillment for the session without using webhooks?

Comment: Hi @Kevin Parker,  It seems like in Dialogflow CX, intent fulfillment can only be achieved through the use of webhooks. So if you want this feature in Dialogflow CX, you can raise a feature request in the i[ssue tracker.](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) For more information refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment).